# put axis index on OpenCV histogram

Tags: opencv, histogram

I want to draw histogram of an image in OpenCV. I use the demo code but there is no index number on x axis nor y axis.

Then I use cvPutText to put some numbers on. Again, cvPutText doesn't support put text in different orientation (just horizon). I want the text to be put vertically

Is there any way around this?

Comment: As a workaround you could rotate the image (maybe using transpose and flip operations), add the text and then rotate the image back.

Comment: that is possible. I can do that. But it means that OpenCV doesn't support such thing?? strange..

Comment: @ShawnLe I also need a solution to this. How did you solve this ?

Comment: Hi user! I didn't do it yet! but it's not difficult, you can give a try